# Android - Way to appear bordered text on the TextView?

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-controls, border

Is there a way to appear bordered text on the TextView ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "bordered text"?

Comment: Thanks response. I mean each letter of text would be bordered. How to make it ? 

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest to extend [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)
See [Android Custom Component Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

[image: android_text_border]

```
package samples.test;
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);       
    }
}
```

Than use it in layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <samples.test.MyTextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Most simple way is use a 9 patch background.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_target"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="000000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_default"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
```