# Is there a simpler/better way to put a border/outline around my TextView?

Tags: xml, textview, border, android

So I wanted to have a TextView with a cool border around it. I couldn't find any standard way of doing it, so I came up with this:

@drawable/custom_bg_1: A blue rounded shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#439CC8"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

@drawable/custom_bg_2: A white rounded shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

myactivity.xml: the xml for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="15dp" >

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_1" >

      <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/curr_loc"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_2" />

  </LinearLayout>
</Linearlayout>
```

The outcome:

[image: picture of blue border]

What I am doing here is overlapping a white shape background inside a blue shape background to give the effect of a blue border. I can't imagine this is the best way to get this effect. I have seen other posts that attempt to solve this problem such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview), but I feel like they are just as much of a work around as my implementation.

Is there a better way or more standard way of simply putting a border around certain views such as a TextView or should I just stick with the way I am doing it?

---

**EDIT**

I changed custom_bg_2.xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

And now I get this result:

[image: blue and black border]

It looks like I can achieve an outline by including `<stroke ... />` in shape.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can probably get by with just custom_bg_2 if you add a <stroke> section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#439CC8" android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Oh, nice! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. It should be noted that when only putting <stroke/> and not <solid/>, the stroke will fill the shape, but when both are used, you get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try **stroke** instead of **solid**?

According to [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) you can do something like:

```
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#439CC8"/>
```

instead of `<solid/>` and then set it as your `TextView` background.

Comment: I tried swapping <stroke ... />code snippet for the <solid ... /> code, yet it seems to have the exact same effect. Is this what stroke is supposed to do?

Comment: yes, it just creates a border. You can get by with just using the single background which has the stroke and leaving the other one out

Comment: I don't want to use `<stroke/>` instead of `<solid/>`, but rather in addition to it. Then the color for stroke outlines the view while the color for solid fills it in.