# How to border only left, top and bottom for TextView

Tags: android

Here is my coding. Here is design blue color for TextView's 4 border. What I want is to design only for 3 borders (top, left and bottom).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#449def" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254562/is-there-a-simpler-better-way-to-put-a-border-outline-around-my-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick solution (probably dumb), add `android:translationX="2dp"` on your `TextView` and you can add `android:paddingRight="2dp"` to make up for lost space.

Answer (score 10):

Below code placed at the bottom of height of 1dp, you have to play with this for other sides

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- This is the line -->
<item>
  <shape>
        <solid android:color="#535353" />
  </shape>
</item>

<!-- This is the main color -->
<item android:bottom="1dp">
 <shape>
       <solid android:color="#252525" />
 </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Refer this discussion [Open-sided Android stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke)

Comment: line and main color is different in the link you gave and I think yours is wrong one. Comments should be changed

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="0dp"
                android:top="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```