# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class... while extending EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I get this error when I try to create custom edittext.What am I doing wrong? 
I tried to run this code from a previous post:
[Extending a EditText in Android. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648924/extending-a-edittext-in-android-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.actionbarimagetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

MyEdiText.java:

```
package com.example.actionbarimagetest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyEditText extends EditText implements OnClickListener {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    }

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public void FlashBorder()
    {
        //do some custom action
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText txt = (EditText) v;
        txt.selectAll();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.actionbarimagetest
        android:id="@+id/edtTaskName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Full stack trace:

```
Process: com.example.actionbarimagetest, PID: 11781
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbarimagetest/com.example.actionbarimagetest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.actionbarimagetest
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.actionbarimagetest
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:319)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
            at com.example.actionbarimagetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.actionbarimagetest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.actionbarimagetest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.actionbarimagetest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:319)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
            at com.example.actionbarimagetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `com.example.actionbarimagetest` by `com.example.actionbarimagetest.MyEditText` in your XML file.

Comment: thanx, that was the problem.

Comment: please mark the answer as the solution it that solved your problem