# How to draw border on just one side of a linear layout?

Tags: android

I'm able to draw border to a linear layout, but it is getting drawn on all sides. I want to restrict it to right side only, like you do in CSS (border-right:1px solid red;).

I've tried this, but it still draws on all sides:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="2dp"
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FF0000" />

        <solid android:color="#000000" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="0dp"
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="0dp" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:radius="1dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

BTW, I do not want to use the hack of putting a view of width 1dp on the required side.

Comment: you can use drawableLeft in your layout

Answer (score 391, accepted):

You can use this to get border on one side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**EDITED**

As many including me wanted to have a one side border with transparent background, I have implemented a `BorderDrawable` which could give me borders with different size and color in the same way as we use css. But this could not be used via xml. For supporting XML, I have added a `BorderFrameLayout` in which your layout can be wrapped.

See my [github](https://github.com/vivekkhandelwal/kLib-android) for the complete source.

Comment: what if you want a solid alpha based color with a bottom border? I have been thinking at a solution to that with the Android Drawable XML   api but i can't figure it out.

Comment: This didn't work for me -- oddly did the inverse of what i wanted a darker color on the inside, with the grey gradient I overlayed for the boarders.  Been thinking about making a rectangle drawable at a certain size to put as a drawableLeft on the item.  This doesn't seem as streamlined.

Comment: @jbenowitz: The order of the item in layer-list is more important. If u reverse then you will get those result.

Comment: I've fixed this by adding a stroke the border color and the shape remaining the button color.  That did the trick.

Answer (score 268):

Easy as pie, allowing a transparent bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#f00"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerX="0.01" />
</shape>
```

Change the angle to change border location:

- 0 = left
- 90 = bottom
- 180 = right
- 270 = top

Comment: This is by far the best answer here, too bad it's not upvoted

Comment: Nice, however I certainly wouldn't describe it as "easy as pie".

Comment: This doesn't work if you need a thicker border or if you need borders on multiple sides.

Comment: How can you set the height of this shape?

Comment: @codeman - use this as a background to your view, then it will inherit its height.

Comment: But my view is a tab within a FragmentTabHost, and I want the height of the border to be like 70% less than the height of the tab and centered vertically.

Comment: @WhereDatApp.com, how to use your solutions in a android layout? Sorry, I am new in Android.

Comment: @GeisonSantos: this xml should actually go into a drawable, then use that drawable as a background to the view you want to have a one-sided border.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I tryed to create a `View` with customizable border in XML (like `border="top|right"`.  
I used `LayerDrawable` to combine each single `border` programmatically. The single `border`s used [`inset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760463/3182091)  which resulted in one `border` overdrawing the other (even with transparent background).  
With this solution it seems to work fine :) Thank you

Comment: @WhereDatApp.com It seems like the border does not update, when height of `View` changes. So it possible draws the border in the middle of the view. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: how to adjust stroke or border width?

Comment: Top and bottom borders look thicker than left and right ones in Android Studio Preview.

Answer (score 114):

it is also possible to implement what you want using a single layer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp"
        android:top="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_of_the_background" />

            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/color_of_the_border" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

this way only left border is visible but you can achieve any combination you want by playing with `bottom`, `left`, `right` and `top` attributes of the `item` element

Comment: This is definitely useful when you have other background color and you want to overlay this drawable bg with border. (y)

Comment: Exactly what I need, but is it right to use negative paddings?

Comment: This is the best solution. I am bothering what does -5dp do there.

Comment: Negative padding is common in HTML/CSS. It simply nudges things the other direction. In my experience, it seems perfectly valid in Android as well.

Comment: Implementations using negative margins don't work well if your layout has clipChildren=false or clipToPadding=false. If this is the case, you can use the solution with two overlapped rectangles, like the proposed by Vivek Khandelwal

Answer (score 107):

To get a border on just one side of a drawable, apply a negative `inset` to the other 3 sides (causing those borders to be drawn off-screen).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetTop="-2dp" 
    android:insetBottom="-2dp"
    android:insetLeft="-2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

[image]

This approach is similar to naykah's answer, but without the use of a `layer-list`.

Comment: very good answer, I just need to change the width and inset to 10dp :) And more, I need border on left, so I change android:insetLeft to android:insetRight. So simple! Keeping Material button click :D

Comment: Exactly what I needed, change `insertX` at the top to decide what borders to show and what not.

Comment: I can even have a solid color of @null and then this method causes no overdraw. Genius. Thank you!

Comment: @user4050065  just change insetLeft to insetRight :)

Comment: Used this to show just left and right. Nice solution!!

Comment: Attention: This will shift the content of your view and will also resize it. Use with care.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it allows a transparent background and allows dp to be specified instead of resorting to the hack of compressing a gradient into a line.

Answer (score 33):

An other great example
[image: example]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:insetRight="-2dp">
     
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <corners
             android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
             android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
             android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
         <stroke
             android:width="1dp"
             android:color="#70b23f" />
         <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
     </shape>
     
</inset>
```

Comment: so far the best for me

Comment: This is the most reliable answer that i've ever seen. Thank you –

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative (if you don't want to use background), you can easily do it by making a view as follows:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

For having a right border only, place this after the layout (where you want to have the border):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

For having a left border only, place this before the layout (where you want to have the border):

Worked for me...Hope its of some help....

Answer (score 7):

I was able to achieve the effect with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="0dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp">
        <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#123456" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can adjust to your needs for border position by changing the direction of displacement

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#f28b24" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#f28b24" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"/>
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f28b24"
                android:endColor="#f28b24"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#f28b24" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no mention about **[nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)** files here. Yes, you have to create the file, however it's quite easy job and it's really "**cross-version and transparency supporting**" solution. If the file is placed to the `drawable-nodpi` directory, it works `px` based, and in the `drawable-mdpi` works approximately as dp base (thanks to resample).

Example file for the original question (*border-right:1px solid red;*) is here:

http://ge.tt/517ZIFC2/v/3?c

Just place it to the `drawable-nodpi` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Borders of different colors. I used 3 items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap into container and define margins for start left bottom top.
Suppose you want to provide margin for left side you can do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    >
    <TextView
        android:marginStart="2dp" // This is Your border
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="a"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```