# BackgroundResource border top and bottom

Tags: java, android

Actually I have this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid 
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="0.5dp" 
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

It creates a border around a view but I want only make a border in top and bottom.

How?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot it should work with state pressed

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"   
        android:drawable="@color/color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211208/how-to-draw-border-on-just-one-side-of-a-linear-layout. try this

Comment: you can check the below post for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

bkg.xml in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 
    </shape>
  </item>   
    <item android:bottom="5dp"   android:top="5dp" >  
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
   </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

Change the color and the stroke width according to your requirements.

Snap Shot of graphical editor

[image]

Edit: To the question in the comment

Define itembkg. xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/bkg" /> 
        // bkg.xml in drawable folder
        // drawable in pressed state 
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/tvnormal" /> 
        // set a different drawable in normal state
</selector>
```

Then in your view add the below attribute

```
android:background="@drawable/itembkg"
```

Comment: How can I combine this with state pressed?

Comment: @user222 check the edit. it works for me i have tried it before posting

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item > 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

       <padding android:top="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />
       <solid android:color="#000000"/>


    </shape>
  </item>
  <item > 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    </shape>
 </item>
 </layer-list>
```