# how to draw android textview shape with rightbottom gradient

Tags: android, textview, android-shape

I am trying to draw `textview` rectangle shape with bottom shadow and rightbottom corner gradient.which look like  *page folded at right bottom corner*
I have tried this,but this giving me right part of shape displaying black, i want only rightbottom corner to be black.

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="93%" 
android:startColor="#FFffff00" 
android:centerColor="#FFffff00" 
android:endColor="#FF000000" 
android:angle="315"/>
</shape>
```

please help
thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211208/how-to-draw-border-on-just-one-side-of-a-linear-layout

Answer (score 0):

Create a background image according to your requirements and set it to your textview.