# Android : Adding bottom border to relativeLayout programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Can anyone explain how to add bottom border to relative layout programatically?
**PS** : I'm using below code for adding border to relative layout:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.borderEffect); 
ShapeDrawable rectShapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();

Paint paint = rectShapeDrawable.getPaint();
paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(rectShapeDrawable);
```

above code adds border for all corners but I want to add border just for bottom.
Is there any way or equivalent way to do that?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212584/1612432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a View to your relative layout:

```
View bottomBorder = new View(CONTEXT);
bottomBorder.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

relativeLayout.addView(bottomBorder, params);
```