# What are insets in android?

Tags: android, insets

I am beginner at android development. I was recently looking at someone else's code and found some functions `view.onApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets), windowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop()`. And this word was used frequently in the same app.

I tried googling it and found `InsetDrwable` class with explanation

> A Drawable that insets another Drawable by a specified distance. This is used when a View needs a background that is smaller than the View's actual bounds.

Can some one explain me what is the meaning on `Insets` and what those piece of code up there meant?

A explanation with an example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Suppose you have a TextView and you need to add a background to the TextView. But, on the other hand, you don't want the background to scan the entire View (TextView), therefore, you need to use Insets.

> A Drawable that insets another Drawable by a specified distance or
> fraction of the content bounds. This is used when a View needs a
> background that is smaller than the View's actual bounds.

The background can be a Drawable. Hence you need to use the `<inset>` attribute inside your xml file (activity_main.xml) "For Example".

Then, after using the `<inset>` tag, you can specify some attributes such as:

```
<inset
    android:drawable="@drawable/(Enter the file name under drawable)"
    android:insetBottom="4dp"
    android:insetTop="4dp"/>
```

For more information please have a look at [InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html) on Android developer.com

Hope this helps!

Comment: here's a [practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760463/2445763) of insets being used