# Android New Message type recipient control

Tags: android, message

Is anyone know how can I replicate/mirror the New message To / Recipient bar functionality, please?  Is there a built in control or widget available or do I have to custom build that?  or is there any examples available?  I tried a few terms but not sure what is the exact term I should be using.  Is used terms like "android message recipient bar", "android message to bar" etc.  but nothing returned that is useful to me...

[image]

still under construction but this is how it looks at present....
[image]

Comment: that looks like a styled button to me

Comment: Looks very iOS-styled to me. Easy to make though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, marginLeft="-1dp" is just quick solution to avoid workaround to create shape with only one side border. To avoid using this dirty solution: [How to draw border on just one side of a linear layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211208/how-to-draw-border-on-just-one-side-of-a-linear-layout)

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Able John"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_right_corners"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5000"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    />

</shape>
```

drawable/background_right_corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5000"
    />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I had to struggle with the layout when I add them to the RelativeLayout dynamically because whatever Params you set in the XML will not work and have to set them dynamically.