# Avoiding a NullReferenceException when creating a custom Android UI element from subclassed TextView

Tags: android-layout, textview, xamarin.android

A couple of firsts here - first Android app and first time using MonoDroid (I've got lots of experience with C# .NET).

In my user interface I want to draw a border around a TextView and found a post on SO ([2026873](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview)) that recommended subclassing TextView. I also found another post ([2695646](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)) with some additional info on declaring a custom Android UI element using XML. (Note: All code in the example posts were in Java, had to translate into the C#/MonoDroid environment.)

When I run the code in the emulator I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's my out-of-the-box Activity1 code and the code for the subclassed TextView.

```
namespace MBTA
{
    [Activity(Label = "MBTA", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }

    public class BorderedTextView : TextView
    {
        public BorderedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle) { }
        public BorderedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) { }
        public BorderedTextview(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw (canvas);

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Stoke);
            paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.White;
            paint.StrokeWidth = 3;

            GetLocalVisibleRect(rect);
            canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

My Main.axml layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MBTA"     
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <MBTA.BorderedTextView
            android:text="DATE"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my attrs.xml file is as follows (with its BuildAction set to AndroidResource):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="BorderedTextView">
        <attr name="android:text"/>
    <attr name="android:textSize"/>
    <attr name="android:layout_width"/>
    <attr name="android:layout_height"/>
    <attr name="android:gravity"/>
    <attr name="android:layout_weight"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono for Android lowercases the namespace name when generating the Java [Android Callable Wrappers](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture/android_callable_wrappers) for use by Android and layout XML files.

Consequently (as noted in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496442/83444)), you need to use `mbta.BorderedTextView`, not `MBTA.BorderedTextView`.

The Mono for Android documentation discuses [using custom views in a layout](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/using_custom_views_in_a_layout), which addresses this scenario.