# how to set the color of the TextView structure?

Tags: android, textview

is there any possible way to set the border around the TextView such like the pics shown below?
the first pic is what i currently got and the second one is what kind of border i want.
all element that contain in the LinearLayout are just indiviual textViews
thx so much for the help~~
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that please check the following link: [Android - Way to appear bordered text on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview) this might help to solve u r problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by setting your TextView background a xml shape that has background and border like this:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#191919" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#191919"/>
  </shape>
```

You can red more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)