# how to write on border of edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to create an edit text which contains some text relevant to that text box. How to do that. Although there are some ways through HTML. But I have no clue how to do that in android. Can any body suggest me something for that. For clear view I am providing sample shot of my requirement.

Any help will appreciated

[image].....

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview

Comment: No help, links are taking me to some other place apart from developer.android one.And also they are suggesting 9 patch image which mean doing it in one image. But I need to do at various places. So any suggestion for my problem....

Comment: I think you can extends `EditText` and override the `draw` methods, if just a border, it will be easy to draw. But you can also draw it like your above picture.

Comment: I don't know much of draw, So Can I use it as generic. I mean Once declare can I use it anywhere with different text on border???????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve somethin like that by doing this way,

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>

        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image of my testing]

Comment: I love you for this. why can't I upvote you more than once.Thanks thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I think using `android:hint` is also useful to place **some text relevant to edit text**.

But, it will show the text only when the edit text is empty and also inside the edit text, but not as you shown here.

I think the layout you shown here may take more time to implement.

Comment: No I need it to be visible at all time, so I can't use it. thanks anyways