# Is there any clickable area that holds a TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to have a clickable listView of items...For each element in the list, I am having a clickable TextView....the problem is that it's too limited for the user to click only on the TextView to access what's inside the element. Instead, I want the whole list item that holds that TextView to be clickable so that the user can easily click anywhere (not specifically on the text). Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

TextView label;
CheckBox checkBox;
Context c = this.getApplicationContext();
private ArrayList<Boolean> status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
String[] objects) {

super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        status.add(false);
    }
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

 View row = convertView;

 if(row==null){
  LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false); 

 }  


 label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
 label.setText(month[position]);
 label.setClickable(true);

//View l = (View)row.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
 label.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The rest just clicked in " + position ,       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

 }   });



 checkBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

         String event = null;

         if (isChecked) 
         {
         status.set(position, true);
         event = " just checked!";
         } 

        else 
         {
         status.set(position, false);
         event = " just unchecked!";
         }

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checkbox " + position +event,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

     }
 });
 checkBox.setChecked(status.get(position));



 return row;
}
}

 String[] month = {
 "January", "February", "March", "April",
"May", "June", "July", "August",
"September", "October", "November", "December"
  };

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.main);
 /*setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek));*/


   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.main, month));



 }













 }
```

Comment: take a look at this question, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview

Comment: So you are using `OnClickListener`? If so, you are doing it wrong. Set an `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView` and that should do it.

Comment: I don't have the normal ViewList, I am inheriting ArrayAdapter and overriding getView method to set each item seperately on my listView...I have two items. a dropbox and a Textview...I want the TextView to be clickable on the whole item.

Comment: What exactly means you don't have a normal ListView? Could you post some cheezbur... source pls? Cause in the end you usually plug in a "source object" like an 'ArrayList' into the ListAdapter via 'setListAdapter()

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
listview.setOnItemOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(....));
```

Comment: as you can see, I don't have a listview variable like this one...check my code above

Comment: you are extending ListViewActivity so

    this..setOnItemOnClickListener()

Comment: no I am not extending ListViewActivity. I am extending ListActivity

Comment: I solved the problem simply by this line,
    checkBox.setFocusable(false);